# Getting ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() while using IF statement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have an array of predicted values and I want to compare it with a threshold. My code is follows:

```
thres = 0.40
  for val in Y_pred:
      if(np.less(max(Y_pred),thres)):
          print("Unknown class")
      else:
          print("Known class")
```

But it gives me the following error:

> File "C:\Users\abc.py", line 230, in pp
> if(np.less(max(Y_pred),thres)):

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I tried the following variations by still I am getting the same error:

```
for val in Y_pred:
      if(np.less(max(Y_pred),thres).all()):
          print("Unknown class")
      else:
          print("Known class")
```

```
for val in Y_pred:
      if(np.all(max(Y_pred)<thres)):
          print("Unknown class")
      else:
          print("Known class")
```

```
for val in Y_pred:
      if(max(Y_pred)<thres.all()):
          print("Unknown class")
      else:
          print("Known class")
```

```
for val in Y_pred:
      if(max(Y_pred)<thres).all():
          print("Unknown class")
      else:
          print("Known class")
```

The Y_pred looks like
[[0.01258 0.09052 0.68866 0.18992 0.01831][0.1101  0.30838 0.1321  0.32835 0.12107][0.11269 0.37349 0.24212 0.18819 0.08351][0.1664  0.30524 0.4782  0.01753 0.03263][0.04549 0.55705 0.38847 0.00692 0.00208]] in my case.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use max(Y_pred) there?

E.g.

```
a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
max(a)
```

prints

```
[3, 4]
```

And if I'm doing np.less(max(a), 3.5), I'm getting back an array, this is what error is about

```
np.less(max(a), 3.5)
```

prints

```
array([ True, False])
```

And why you're iterating val over  Y_pred and not using it at all?

Comment: My Y_pred is a numpy array and you are considering 'a' as a list. However, I got my mistake. Instead of if(np.less(max(Y_pred),thres)):, I should have used if(np.less(max(val),thres)):

Thank you!